# Where is the Consortium of Trao?

Tags: farscape

In the Farscape episode 'Throne for a Loss' (season one, episode four) The Trao are introduced as the first of their line is imprisoned with Rygel. It is explained by Jotheb that the Trao span many worlds (around 10,000) and have a population of approximately 40 trillion. Whenever Rygel says he's never heard of the Trao, Jotheb says that the imperfection is his which seems to imply that the Trao have also interacted with many other races.

**As it seems they are at least as powerful as the Peacekeepers or the Scarrans so I'm wondering, where are the Trao after this episode and why don't we seem them again?**

Please note that I'm looking for a in-universe answer.

Comment: Given that they were only ever mentioned in that one episode, I'm not sure there can be an in-universe answer to this question.

Comment: @Andy - I agree. As with most [one-note joke characters](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13543/what-is-a-one-note-joke), they served their purpose in the episode and were promptly forgotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "**we don't know**". Not only do we not see any real star maps within the series but the galactic geography of Farscape is baffling at best.

We know that the Hynerian empire has recently been annexed by the Peacekeepers and we know that the Peacekeeper Empire borders the Uncharted Territories and that somewhere along the Peacekeeper border is the Skarran Empire. Beyond that we don't really have much of a clue of their positions relative to each other, their *sizes* relative to each other or their populations relative to each other.

Hypothetically, it may be that the Consortium of Trao is contained wholly within the Uncharted Territories (which would explain why Rygel hasn't heard of them) or that it's along the anterior border of Scarran space or it may simply be that Rygel is clueless about geography outside of his own back yard.

[image]

Comment: @lankill - Did you like the map? It's totally fictitious and bears no relation to anything.